# Blue square around menu

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am using [getmdl.io](http://getmdl.io) to make my android hybrid app and the only problem is that when I click on the menu icon, a blue square appears around it, I tried to add a `cursor:default` in css but it's not working. I also searched here and on google and I can't find anything. If anyone could help me, it would be really appreciated...
[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` in css